# Uncaught ReferenceError: for onclick

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular7

I am getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: for onclick event handler

```
  <ng-conatiner *ngIf="x else y" >
     <div onclick="x()"> {{x.getText()}} </div> 
  </ng-conatiner>

   <ng-template #y>
    <div>{{y.getText()}}</div>
   </ng-template>

  export class A implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("in ngOnInit");    
    } 
    x(){
        console.log("clicked");
     }

  }
```

expected result would be see clicked in console but i am getting uncaught reference error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `(click)="x()"` instead of `onclick`

```
<ng-conatiner *ngIf="x else y" >
     <div (click)="x()"> {{x.getText()}} </div> 
 </ng-conatiner>
```

Here is Angular's documentation page for further reading:
https://angular.io/guide/user-input

**UPDATE**

Here is a tutorial about event binding:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/responding_to_component_events.html

Comment: could you please explain the reason?

Comment: according to my understanding click is used only with buttons where as onclick can be used used with div and other components as well

Comment: The parenthesis means `output` and you are binding the `click` event output to your method. You should use `(click)` regardless of the DOM element type.

Comment: I am often getting confused with (click) vs onclick. Could you please suggest me a blog or material to go through?

Comment: I added a tutorial link in answer. Please have a look at **update** section.

Comment: thanqqqq so much

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `(click)=x()` .
`click` and `onClick` are the same event. You should use `onclick` when assign handler inline and `click` when assign using an event listener.

> The **on-event** handlers are a group of properties offered by DOM elements to help manage how that element reacts to events

In angular we use event listener so `click` is used.:

```
 <ng-conatiner *ngIf="x else y" >
     <div (click)="x()"> {{x.getText()}} </div> 
 </ng-conatiner>
```